# SignalR Core : How to send message to a specific user from a Controller or Repository

Tags: asp.net-core, signalr, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-signalr

In the old version we use `GlobalHost` like

```
var hubContext = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<MyHub>();
hubContext.Clients.addNotification("Bla la la ");
```

But how to do it in the new alpha version ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to inject `IHubContext<THub>` and then should be able to invoke methods.

```
class HubMethods
{
    private IHubContext<THub> _hubContext;
    public HubMethods(IHubContext<THub> hubContext)
    {
        _hubContext = hubContext;
    }

    public Task WriteMessageAsync(string method, param object[] args)
    {
        return _hubContext.Clients.All.InvokeAsync(method, args);
    }
}
```

Comment: The question says _specific_ user. How do we do that?

Comment: @JamesPoulose https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/hubs?view=aspnetcore-2.2#send-messages-to-clients